# keeping mail from going into the sent folder when using Exhange Web Service to send

Tags: c#, wcf, exchange-server

We are using Exchange Web Services to send mail in out WCF application, here is a little code snippet.

```
//using ExchangeWebServices;          
var email = new MessageType();
email.IsFromMe = false;

email.From = new SingleRecipientType();
email.From.Item = new EmailAddressType();
email.From.Item.EmailAddress = message.From;

email.ToRecipients = message.To.Select(to => new EmailAddressType { EmailAddress = to }).ToArray();
```

It works fine but it's filling up the sent mail folder in for the "appserver" user who sends the mail. Is this something we can configure in the app to "not copy it to the sent folder" or does this need to be done by an administrator for the exchange serer?

The reason I ask is cause the admin is a third party consultant so if it could be done without bothering them that would be great.

Thanks! Happy Holidays!

Comment: to clarify for anyone else this is a WCF service that runs internally that our desktop clients connect to, we send out lots of notifications internally for various things, i.e. new order, etc... We don't care about the sent mail box for system account that sends these emails.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is an option or not, but if you can use SmtpClient rather than Exchange Web Services, you can send email without a copy going to a 'sent mail' folder.  Obviously you have access to an Exchange server, so you'd just need to have Exchange's SMTP server configured such that your application server can relay through it.  Otherwise you could setup a new SMTP server using the SMTP functionality included in IIS:

[SmtpClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient.aspx)

[Configuring SMTP in IIS 7](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772058%28WS.10%29.aspx)